# How to encourage use-mention distinction?

Tags: discussion, style-guide

Almost every answer on the site could use editing to mark the words being used as examples. I don't really feel comfortable editing a bunch of posts just for this reason; plus, I feel like I can't keep up. How can we encourage people (mostly the answerers, though also the askers to some extent) to make use of the formatting options available?

So instead of

> Formally, if should be used when you have a conditional sentence and whether should be used when you are showing that two alternatives are possible.

which is hard to parse, we should encourage something like

> Formally, *if* should be used when you have a conditional sentence and *whether* should be used when you are showing that two alternatives are possible.

Comment: Every post I want to yell 'use quotes'!!

Comment: Very good question. As to the answer—I wish I knew!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My practise on ELU has evolved towards this (though I haven’t been altogether consistent):

- Mark both technical terms and ‘mentioned’ words or phrases in *italics*, as in your example
- Mark literal quotations and longer constructions employed as examples in “double quotes”—this leaves it possible to mark the ‘mentioned’ terms in italics, as before
- Mark allusions and non-standard, colloquial or ironic uses in ‘single quotes’
- Mark rhetorical emphasis with **bold** or ***bold italics***, depending on typographical context

But I’m not wedded to this. If the Community wants something different I’ll go along. And if left to my own devices I might change anyway, since the typeface here seems antipathetic to quotation marks.

Comment: The quote marks here aren’t particularly distinctive because the font is basically a bog standard sans clone along Helvetica lines. Hopefully at some point the font will be changed to a decent serif which should help readability and make the quote marks more ‘curly’.

Comment: As I grew bored of English curly quotes eating my words on the [FL&U beta](http://french.stackexchange.com/), I ‘saved ’ the Unicode hair space for easy access. You can find such interesting spaces [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html). I'll borrow your fine use of single quotes, sir =) (You don't seem so mention foreign words ? I use italics (*aperçu* ) for them, which sometimes forces quotes for ‘mentions’ to distinguish them.)

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks  Yah, I write most of my posts in Word, in a stock file I keep which has all the spaces, dashes, diacritized characters I use, the IPA characters, OE and OW characters, and a handful of other useful glyphs in an order where I can find them more easily than in Unicode tables. Foreign terms, yes, I italicize those, too.

Comment: I mention and literal-quote with double quotation marks, bold to call attention to a word, and italicize for foreign words and emphasis. The only things I put in single quotation marks are nested quotations and mentions of a single character. I'm glad I discovered this post, as I've long wondered how and why your system is so different from my own.